# How to render list of item using select and option and add link to navigate to the id of each

Tags: reactjs

```
 <Label >Movies:</Label>
      <Selected>
       {movie.map((item)=>{
        return<>
       <Link><Option>{item.name}</Option></Link>
        </>
       })}
      </Selected>
```

I'm trying to get the id of each element of the list and use prams property
but it says I can't use the link inside select. I have tried many Libraries but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<Label >Movies:</Label>
<Selected>
         {movie.map((item)=>(<Option><Link href=`api/${item.id}`>{item.name}</Link></Option>)
       })}
</Selected>
```

Comment: It didn't work, says react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a child of <option>

Comment: Try to wrap Link tag with a div tag